# no connection between postgresql DB and eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, postgresql

I am trying to put up a Postgres DB for my DWP in Eclipse Mars. 
After going through all the steps of creation eclipse says that there is a problem with connection

In detailed ping I get this

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: �����: ������������ "postgres" �� ������ �������� ����������� (�� ������)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:415)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:188)
at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:64)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:143)
at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:29)
at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:21)
at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:38)
at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.<init>(Jdbc4Connection.java:24)
at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:412)
at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:280)
at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.internal.postgresql.PostgreSQLJDBCConnection.createConnection(PostgreSQLJDBCConnection.java:87)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.internalCreateConnection(DriverConnectionBase.java:105)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.open(DriverConnectionBase.java:54)
at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.internal.postgresql.PostgreSQLJDBCConnection.<init>(PostgreSQLJDBCConnection.java:47)
at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.internal.postgresql.PostgreSQLConnectionFactory.createConnection(PostgreSQLConnectionFactory.java:51)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionFactoryProvider.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryProvider.java:83)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionProfile.createConnection(ConnectionProfile.java:359)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.createTestConnection(PingJob.java:76)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.run(PingJob.java:59)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

What it might be caused by ?

I use 
Eclipse Mars Release (4.5.0), PostgreSQL 9.3, JDK 1.8, And driver 9.3-1103 JDBC 41 what pretty much suits my version

Comment: What exactly is the exception message?

Comment: It's really hard to say, as the message has been lost in encoding conversion, and you don't show the connection properties. Please try to give more information (but remember to hide password or other private data).